# android devices use "dd" command to write a kernel to mmcblk can't bootable

Tags: android, recovery, u-boot

i have a android devices boot with u-boot .this devices has a emmc which named in dev as /dev/block/mmcblk0.there is 4 partations on it . /dev/block/mmcblk0p{1,2,3,4} . i had know that mmcblk0p1 is MLO , mmcblk0p2 is u-boot.bin ,mmcblk0p3 is kernel , mmcblk0p4 is recovery.I want to try if i can write the mmcblk directly with dd command in shell. so i use this command to write a file to mmcblk0p3

`dd if=FILE_WRITE_IN of=/dev/block/mmcblk0p3`

i don't write the mmcblk0p4 ,i think i can recovery my system use the recovery system.
but when i reboot my devices,i can even boot into the recovery system. how the u-boot boot the recovery partation ,if the recovery partation depend on the kernel partation? why can't boot the recovery.

Comment: Typically a recovery partition would include it's own copy of a kernel, to make a complete stand-alone repair system.  Beyond that, it's unclear what your question is, or if this is even a workable approach on your unspecified device.  You should probably seek advice/guides from those with experience customizing android on the device in question.

Comment: The `dd` command looks okay, except that `FILE_WRITE_IN` had better be a `uImage` kernel file for U-Boot.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes ,i know the recovery has a kernel,so i just write the uImage to the kernel partition,and i don't write the recovery partition any more.I don't know if these partions are independed.how uboot boot the recovery . and has anyone use the "dd" command to update a kernel partition? I know typically we update kernel partition with fastboot.

Comment: It is precisely to make it independent that a recovery usually has its own kernel.